# Proof of a solution of a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Proof that  $$ x=a(\theta - \sin(\theta))$$ $$y=a(1-\cos(\theta))$$ where $a$ is a constant different from zero is a solution of the differential equation $$1+(y')^2+2yy'=0$$.

$\textit{What I've done:}$
I found $$y'= \frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{\frac{da-a\cos(\theta)}{d\theta}}{\frac{da-a\cos(\theta)}{d\theta}}=\frac{a\sin(\theta)}{a(1-\cos(\theta))}=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}$$

So substituting this on our differential equation we have: $$1+(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)})^2+2[(a-a\cos(\theta))(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)})]=1+(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)})^2+2a\sin(\theta)$$ There's where I got stuck. I don't know what else to do. Help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

$$\cancel{1}+\cancel{(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)})^2}+2[(a-a\cos(\theta))(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)})]=\cancel{1}+\cancel{(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)})^2}+2a\sin(\theta)$$

$$\cancel{2}[(a-a\cos(\theta))(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)})]=\cancel{2}a\sin(\theta)$$

$$(a-a\cos(\theta))\cdot\sin(\theta)=a\sin(\theta)-a\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$

$$a\sin(\theta)-a\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)=a\sin(\theta)-a\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$$

$$0=0$$
$\square$

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are welcome!